# Why does passing a HEREDOC as a string to `ruby -e` not work?

Tags: quoting, ruby, here-document

For reasons I don't understand, it seems to be impossible to pass a heredoc as an expression to a Ruby interpreter:

```
$ ruby -e <<END
heredoc> puts 'hi'
heredoc> END

ruby: no code specified for -e (RuntimeError)
```

The same thing happens with Perl, to make it painfully obvious that it has nothing to do with Ruby.

```
$ perl -e<<END
heredoc> print 'hi'
heredoc> END
No code specified for -e.
```

And even with `sed`:

```
$ echo "blah" | sed -e <<END
pipe heredoc> s/.*/Hi/
pipe heredoc> END
sed: option requires an argument -- e
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
```

How can I pass a heredoc as an expression to Ruby? (or Perl, or Sed...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because creating a giant string and passing it as an argument isn't what "here documents" do. They create a stream, which can be connected to some job's input.

Concretely,

```
cat <<!
foo
!
```

is not equivalent to

```
cat foo
```

.

Speaking of `cat`, it can help us out here. Warning: **non-** useless use of `cat` follows!

```
echo $(cat <<!
foo
!
)
```

See, we **can** pass a here doc as an argument, thanks to command substitution applied to `cat` which has been fed a here doc.

Comment: You provided the key insight (and answered first!) and it was fairly obvious to me after reading your answer that I could add double quotes around the the `$()` expression, but it might not be so obvious to everyone who reads this later, so I'm torn on which answer to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ perl -e "$(cat <<'EOF'
print 'qwerty';
EOF
)"
qwerty
```

You must use double quote for `perl` to know what program to run, and `bash` to expand here document.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e "<<'EOF'
print 'qwerty';
EOF
"
'???';
-e syntax OK
```

You can see, `perl` see your input as string only.

With `cat` and `process substitution`:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e "$(cat <<'EOF'
print 'qwerty';
EOF
)
"
print 'qwerty';
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: Initially I thought this was flawed because I wouldn't be able to use double quotes inside the code, but then realized that even though the HEREDOC is a stream rather than a string (as Kaz points out) it will still hide any internal double quotes from the shell interpreter.

Comment: @iconoclast: You must quote `heredoc` delimiter, in this case is `'EOF'` to make all things in `heredoc` literally.

Answer (score 1):

`-e` requires an argument, the code to execute. You can use a string with embedded newlines. This to me is the most readable. Works with ruby, perl, sed ...

```
ruby -e '
  1.upto(10) do |n|
    p [n, n.even?]
  end
'
```

You can pass the ruby/perl code to the interpreter via stdin, but then you can't pass any filename arguments, nor can you read data from stdin (*)

```
ruby <<'END'
  1.upto(10) do |n|
    p [n, n.even?]
  end
END
```

(*) this is pretty gross: you can send the program *and* the data on stdin, using ruby's (and perl's) DATA filehandle:

```
{
    cat <<'END'
while (<DATA>) {print +(split /:/)[0], "\n"}
__END__
END
    cat /etc/passwd
} | perl
```